# How to uninstall ubuntu 15.04 from macbook pro?

Tags: 15.04

Can i uninstall ubuntu from the Disk Utility of mac by deleting the partition or is there any other way. Will be thankful.

Comment: I thought you should make secure erase , but before you uninstall think alittle because you are with the perfect unix os

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps to completely remove Ubuntu from MacOS:

1. Boot from your Ubuntu Live CD or USB device.
2. Once you are in Ubuntu start `Disk Utility` (gparted).
3. Find your linux partitions and delete them.
4. Set the `swap` to 'off' and then delete that partition.
5. Reboot into MacOS
6. Start the `Disk Utility` application and go to ‘Partition’
7. Re-size the Mac OS partition as you like

Comment: What if there is no MacOS to reboot into? I deleted all Mac partitions and installed Ubuntu, and now can't boot from a USB or DVD nor recovery partitions.